# Intersection Formula

Tags: tangent-line

Hi Kindly help to solve.
How to find the distance from center of vertical object to Intersection point?
Please help me derive a formula.

[image: click here]

Comment: I can't tell what lines up with what in the figure, so cannot answer.  What does this have to do with a tangent point?

Comment: Can you see the picture? I cannot see it after I attach it

Comment: I see a picture with a red circle and underneath that a short vertical red segment and to the right of that three question marks. There are also many other features in the picture, hard to be sure what you are referring to. There are no evident tangent lines anywhere in the picture. The point at the center of the circle is at the intersection of an arc with a non-tangent line.

Comment: Assuming "???" denotes the distance to be calculated, you need to know the radius of the larger arc and how the center is located relative to the other objects in the picture.

Comment: Yes, I can see it, which surprises me.  Usually you need some more reputation to put in graphics.  But I can't understand it from the perspective.

Comment: The radius of the object with arc is 30mm and the center of the object(with arc) is aligned with the center of the 2nd object (the one intersects with arc). Sorry I just edited the question and thread title. It is not tangential but an intersection.

Comment: I want to know the formula on getting the distance from center of object to intersection point.